# Behat in Multiple Browsers in Parallel

Tags: selenium, jenkins, bdd, behat, mink

We currently use [Behat 3](http://docs.behat.org/en/latest/) to automate BDD tests for our website.

The current setup uses [Jenkins](https://jenkins-ci.org/) to run [Selenium](http://www.seleniumhq.org/) which attaches to [Firefox](https://www.mozilla.org/en-GB/firefox/new/) and uses [XVFB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xvfb) to render (this allows us to save screenshots when anything goes wrong).

This is great for testing that the site (including JavaScript) works and that a user can perform each documented task successfully.

I am looking to expand our testing facilities, and one thing I would like to add is the ability to check multiple browsers. This is very important as we get occasional quirks that can break functionality.

Since the tests currently take slightly over an hour to run (and we have 4 suites for that site on Jenkins), I'd preferably like to run all the browsers at the same time. If I can't find a way to do it concurrently, then I likely will just set up multiple Behat profiles and run each one in series.

One thing I've been looking at as a possible solution is [Ghostlab](http://vanamco.com/ghostlab/). This would allow us to test across, multiple browsers and multiple devices, including mobile, at the same time. The problem is that I can't find a way of joining this to Behat in a meaningful way.

I could run one browser connected to Ghostlab, which would cause the same actions to be taken across all connected browsers, however, were a browser other than the one controlled by Selenium to break, I do not know how we would capture that information.

TL;DR: Is there any way for me to run BDD (preferable Behat) tests across multiple browsers in parallel, and capture information from any browser that fails?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what [multi-configuration jobs](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Building+a+matrix+project) (or matrix jobs) are designed for in Jenkins.

You specify your job configuration once, but add one or more variables that should change each time, building a matrix of combinations (in your case, the matrix has one dimension: browser).

[image: Matrix definition]

Jenkins then runs one main build with multiple sub-builds in parallel — one for each combination in the matrix.  You can then clearly see the results for each combination.

[image: Matrix configurations and results]

This requires that your test job can be parameterised, i.e. you can choose at runtime which browser should be run, rather than running all tests together in a single job.

The Jenkins wiki has minimal documentation on this feature, but there are a few good [blog posts](http://blog.smartbear.com/test-automation/running-testcomplete-tests-with-multi-configuration-jenkins-projects/) (and Stack Overflow questions) out there on how to set it up.

A matrix job will use all available "executors" in Jenkins, to run builds in parallel as much as possible.
In a default Jenkins installation, there are two executors availble, but you can change this, or extend Jenkins by adding [further build machines](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Distributed+builds).

Comment: I like this answer and I was aware of this feature however I avoided it due to database changes that happen during E2E tests. As it's a website I'm testing it is difficult (though not impossible) to arbitrarily create and destroy virtual hosts and database schemas. Additionally I still wouldn't be able to test mobile, etc. If no other answers appear that will solve those issues I'll mark this as correct, but I was hoping for an easier way to do it. Hmm... I wonder if I could do it using multi-configuration jobs and with virtual machines.

Comment: I'm going to say this is the correct answer, and the build should either be run in a container or vm.